# flutter-audio players (pubspec.yaml error)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-audioplayers

I have error I think it is on pubspec.yaml I did not completely understand the readme on [fluter packages](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/contributing.md)
this is the code :

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final player = AudioCache();
                player.play('7.mp3');
              },
              child: Text(''),
            )
```

this is pubspec.yaml ( dependencies ) :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^3.0.1
  audioplayers: ^5.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

this is the error

```
>[appname] flutter pub get Running "flutter pub get" in appname...          The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.6. Because appname depends on
> audioplayers >=4.1.0 which requires SDK version >=2.18.0 <3.0.0 or
> >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because appname depends on audioplayers >=4.1.0 which requires SDK version
> >=2.18.0 <3.0.0 or >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.) exit code 1
```

thank you for reading please if you know what is wrong help me !! I am new flutter learner

I tried to chance the pubspec.yaml ( dependencies ) : form
audioplayers: ^5.1.0 to 4.1.0 and delete audioplayers: ^3.0.1

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^4.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is clear, your environment SDK is low.

You need to upgrade your environment in pubspec.yaml to something like

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'
```

and make sure you add any plugin/package only once